# Understanding State Groups in Context in Drake

Tags: drake

I've created a diagram with an LQR Controller, a MultiBodyPlant, a scenegraph, and a PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer.

While trying to run this simulation, I set the random initial conditions using the function: `context.SetDiscreteState(randInitState)`. However, with this, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Context::SetDiscreteState(): expected exactly 1 discrete state group but there were 2 groups. Use the other signature if you have multiple groups.`

And indeed when I check the number of groups using `context.num_discrete_state_groups()`, it returns 2. So, then I have to specify the group index while setting the state using the command `context.SetDiscreteState(0, randInitState)`. This works but I don't exactly know why. I understand that I have to select a correct group to set the state for but what exactly is a group here? In the cartpole example given [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/examples/lqr.ipynb), the context was set using `context.SetContinuousState(UprightState() + 0.1 * np.random.randn(4,))` without specifying any group(s).

Are groups only valid for discrete systems? The context [documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_context.html) talks about groups and but doesn't define them.

Is there a place to find the definition of what a group is while setting up a drake simulation with multiple systems inside a diagram and how to check the group index of a system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would typically recommend that you use a workflow that sets the context using a subsystem interface.  E.g.

```
plant_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(context)
plant_context.SetContinuousState(...)
```

Figuring out the discrete index of a state group for a `DiagramContext` might be possible, but it's certainly not typical.

You might find it helpful to print the context.  In pydrake, you can actually just call `print(context)`, and you will see the different elements and where they are coming from.